# How do I undefine the value for a hash key in Perl?

Tags: perl, hash

How can I undefine the value for a hash key in Perl? How can my code be corrected?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
my %hash;

undef($hash{"a"});
undef($hash{"b"});
print scalar values %hash; # Here I need 0
print scalar keys %hash; # And 2 here
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Alexandr Ciornii's point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1943564/how-do-i-undefine-the-value-for-a-hash-key-in-perl/1943586#1943586) about definedness vs. existence is a very good one, but *if* you actually *do* want to know the number of defined values, you can always do:

```
print scalar grep { defined $_ } values %hash
```

Comment: Surely you mean `values %hash`.

Comment: yeap, that's exactly what i need!

Answer (score 8):

```
undef($hash{"a"});
```

is equivalent to

```
$hash{"a"} = undef;
```

So you add key 'a' with value undef. To delete a value from a hash, use "delete".

```
delete $hash{"a"};
```

It is not possible to have different sizes of 'keys' and 'values' for the same hash. You can use grep to filter unwanted elements.

Comment: sorry for being not descriptive in my question, now i guess is more clear. thank you.

Comment: What grep? Linux command-line tool? Or something else (Perl function or similar)?

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
undef $hash{$key};
```

This will undef the value for this key:

```
print "E" if exists $hash{$key};    # Will print E
print "D" if defined $hash{$key};   # Will not print D
```